# Not able to execute Remote-Connection:Rebuild and Reopen in Container in VS Code for docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run python code from VS code(Visual Studio Code) using Remote Containers for docker. I have installed 1. Remote Container, Docker and Remote SSH plugin and created a docker file. Below Docker file:

```
FROM opt_image:latest
ARG USERNAME=abc
ARG USER_UID=444
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
&& useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y sudo \
&& echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
&& chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAM
USER ${USERNAME}
```

Below my devcontainer.json file:

```
{
"name": "Python 3",
"build": {
"dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
"context": "..",
"args": { 
// Update 'VARIANT' to pick a Python version: 3, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9
"VARIANT": "3.7",
// Options
"NODE_VERSION": "14"
}
},
// Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
"settings": { 
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/autopep8",
"python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/black",
"python.formatting.yapfPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/yapf",
"python.linting.banditPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/bandit",
"python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/flake8",
"python.linting.mypyPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/mypy",
"python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pycodestyle",
"python.linting.pydocstylePath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pydocstyle",
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/pylint"
},   
// Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
"extensions": [
"ms-python.python",
"ms-python.vscode-pylance"
],
// Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
"forwardPorts": [8080],
// Use 'postCreateCommand' to run commands after the container is created.
// "postCreateCommand": "pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt",
"containerEnv": {"CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING":"true"},
// Comment out connect as root instead. More info: https://aka.ms/vscode- 
remote/containers/non-root.
"remoteUser": "abc"
}
```

When I run Remote-Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in container command from Visual Studio Code, I am getting below error:

> Stop (1032 ms): Downloading VS Code Server [2021-08-26T10:55:41.031Z]
> Error: certificate signature failure at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure
> (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20) at
> TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8) at
> TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)

I have installed VS Code Server manually and started from systemd using below command:

```
systemctl enable code-server
systemctl status code-server
```

Its Enabled properly, below is status:

```
Loaded:loaded /etc/systemd/system/code-server.service enabled.vendor preset: enabled
Active:active(running) since Thu 2021-08-26 05:52:58 CDT.27s ago.
```

But still got the same issue. is there something, I am doing wrong. could you please help me about this ?